# Python: APNs error with pyapns_client3 package: 'check your code and try again later'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hey guys I am trying to send apple push notification for voip call and I am using this package `pyapns-client3==3.0.5`. I have setup the voip services and certificates as per the apple developer documentation. But when I try to send notification, I am getting this exception `check your code and try again later` and I can't find the error in my code. Can someone help with solving this issue? Or is there a better package or code to send apple push notification?

```
alert = IOSPayloadAlert(title=f"Call From {name}", subtitle='Incoming call', 
body=f'Incoming call from {name}')
                payload = IOSPayload(alert=alert)
                notification = IOSNotification(
                    payload=payload, 
                    topic='com.company.app', // bundle identifier
                    push_type="voip",
                )
                
                with APNSClient(
                    mode=APNSClient.MODE_PROD,
                    authentificator=TokenBasedAuth(
                        auth_key_path=f"{settings.APNS_AUTH_KEY}",
                        auth_key_id=settings.APNS_KEY_ID,
                        team_id='XXXXXXXXX'
                    ),
                    root_cert_path=None,

                ) as client:
                    try:
                        client.push(notification=notification, device_token=apn_token)

                    except UnregisteredException as e:
                        logger.info(f'device is unregistered, compare timestamp {e.timestamp_datetime} and remove from db')
                    except APNSDeviceException:
                        logger.info('flag the device as potentially invalid and remove from db after a few tries')
                    except APNSServerException:
                        logger.info(f"try again later")
                    except APNSProgrammingException:
                        logger.info('check your code and try again later')

                    else:
                        logger.info('everything is ok')
```

Can anyone help with a better approach or help find error in this code?

Thanks

Comment: Show the stack trace.